# MVC Membership Kit Question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have my site up and running just fine using the kit.

My question is, when you click on the check box to stay logged in, is their a way to extend the amount of time that you stay logged in for.  My client would like something like an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase `authentication/forms/timeout` value in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="60"/>
</authentication>
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx):

> Specifies the time, in integer minutes, after which the cookie expires. ... The default is "30" (30 minutes).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you set this in your Forms timeout in the web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
```

Which is currently set to 48 hours (2880/60).

Change it to 60 if you'd like an hour. Although, something much longer would be more appropriate.